# Failed to connect to SQL Database Premium Plan on Bluemix (Error code SQL1776N)

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, sqldb

I develop an application using "Ruby on Rails runtime" and "SQL Database Premium Plan" on Bluemix.
When I restart the application, it cannot connect to SQL Database.
 
The application was operating normally until yesterday.
How can I solve this problem?

Log Messages

```
2016-04-22T16:19:37.748+0900[App/0]ERRFailed to connect to [IXXXXXXX] due to: uncaught throw :"Connection failed: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1776N The command cannot be issued on an HADR database. Reason code = \"1\". SQLCODE=-1776"
2016-04-22T16:19:37.748+0900[App/0]ERRrake aborted!
2016-04-22T16:19:37.749+0900[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
2016-04-22T16:19:37.749+0900[App/0]ERR/home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a temporary issue, it should start to work again shortly. If the problem persists you could open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the 
     upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support 
     widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch , select the type of 
     assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Please remember to provide the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable value to the SQL Database team.